# How to check if the watch is round or square

Tags: garmin, connectiq

Is there a possibility from the connectIQ API to check if the watch is round or square?

My app is drawing a progress bar for a timer and I could make it generic if I find a way to determine if the screen is round or square

Answer (score 4):

The class [`Toybox::System::DeviceSettings`](https://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/System/DeviceSettings.html) has the method [`screenShape()`](https://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/System/DeviceSettings.html#screenShape-instance_method).

With the following possible return values:

- `SCREEN_SHAPE_ROUND = 1`
- `SCREEN_SHAPE_SEMI_ROUND = 2`
- `SCREEN_SHAPE_RECTANGLE = 3`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the [resource compiler](http://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/resource-compiler/) to specify resources for different screen geometry. This can be leveraged to identify on which device an app is running.

In your project, specify a unique set of resources (which includes things like strings, images, and menus) for each device you intend to support by creating device-specific directories in the root of the project (e.g. *resources-vivoactive* or *resources-fenix3*).

Next, create a string resource in the *resources.xml* file within each devices' resource directory that specifies the device type:

```
<resources>
    <bitmap id="LauncherIcon" filename="images/launcher_icon.png" />
    <string id="AppName">MyApp</string>
    <string id="deviceType">vivoactive</string>
</resources>
```

When the app starts, do a simple check to get the device on which the app is running:

```
function onStart() {
    deviceType = Ui.loadResource(Rez.Strings.deviceType);
}
```

Then, check the *deviceType* whenever if you need to do something unique for a particular device:

```
function drawProgressBar() {
    if (deviceType.equals("vivoactive")) {
        // Do vivoactive-specific stuff here
        ...
    }
}
```

You could abstract this a little if you prefer, buy using more generic deviceTypes like 'round', 'square', etc., so you wouldn't have to write logic to handle every unique device model.

Comment: You can check the shape of the device screen by checking the value of `Sys.getDeviceSettings().screenShape`. The documentation for it can be found [here](http://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/System/DeviceSettings.html#screenShape-instance_method).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a direct function but you can always check for watch face's width and height:

```
dc.getWidth(), dc.getHeight()
```

If they're equal, say, 218px, you have a **Fenix 3** and obviously a round face. If they're 205px x 148px, you're dealing with a square-faced **vívoactive**.

Maybe write a function you can call from onLayout:

```
function isRoundFace (dc) {
    return dc.getWidth() == dc.getHeight();
}
```